# Azure CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher() invalid after upgrading to 2.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-service-runtime

Hi I am struggling to understand/find a solution to this problem. I have removed the reference to StorageClient 1.7 and the project now uses Storage (2.0). I have a web role like this:

```
 public override bool OnStart()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount.SetConfigurationSettingPublisher((configName, configSetter) =>     
configSetter(
           RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue(configName)));
```

The method SetConfigurationSettingPublisher() does not exist.

Whats does this method do, and how do I replace it? 
I have seen things like below but don't understand what's happening. What is the _cloudStorageAccount variable and where is it used? What the point of assigning it to this variable? Would storageSettingName be "DataConnectionString" from Service config? Do I need this at all or can it be omitted?

- var setting = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting(storageSettingName);
- _cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(setting);

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation for [CloudStorageAccount.Parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.cloudstorageaccount.parse.aspx) shows how to use it:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = 
CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageAccountConnectionString"]);
```

The StorageAccountConnectionString would be a setting in your csdef/cscfg which would look something like:

```
<Setting name="StorageAccountConnectionString"
         value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=myaccount;AccountKey=+Ngl4GVRy01UUy5uL4cFqoufI/79xWqBAHkNmYODycfY8QW5dZXzqg58AZl1XxJWvGgEUdW/smr1DvfwuyC1jw==" 
         />
```